# How to access windows certificate store in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, certificate, store

I want to access the windows certificate store through javascript... I want to develop a web application and wants to validate the login user against the certificate by reading it.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know it is not possible from a web application without using native bridge (fir instance through some java applet or activeX component).

There is currently a W3C working draft for a [Web Cryptography API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/). Some browser vendors are currently working on this API ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.crypto) or [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) but it is far from being production ready.